# Is Get; Set property syntaxes makes any difference?

Tags: c#, properties, automatic-properties

I am new to C# language. There are different syntax for Get; Set property. Like

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    set
    {
        this.name = value;
    }
}


public string Name 
    { 
      get { return _name; }
      set { _name = value; }
    }

protected string Name { get; set; }
```

What is the difference between these syntax? Does following different syntax have any impact on functionality? or all the syntax will perform same function?

Comment: Please read the linked answers. If they are unclear, please let us know. Currently your question is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: thanks. i got the answer from the link under the question :)

Comment: Please use the search functionality on this site and google. This question has been asked multiple times, so it should be easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two syntaxes are exactly the same, because you can safle omit `this` keyword.

Third works exactly the same but generates backing field automatically making the code shorter and easier to write.